# Use BuildKit for docker build within Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, dockerfile, docker-buildkit

I am using this Ansible module `community.docker.docker_image` to build docker images. I wanted to use the `--secret` flag and therefore I need to enable BuildKit.

I did edit the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file and added this line `"features": { "buildkit": true }` then restarted the docker service.

However, Ansible still showing error when running;

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error building local:5000/test - code: None, message: the --mount option requires BuildKit. Refer to https://docs.docker.com/go/buildkit/ to learn how to build images with BuildKit enabled ...
```

ansible task:

```
- name: Build an image and push it to a private repo
  community.docker.docker_image:
    build:
      path: "{{ role_path }}/files/test"
      args:
        secret: 'id=test_app_secret_id,src={{ tempfile_1.path }}'
    name: local:5000/test
    tag: v1.1.2
    push: yes
    force_tag: yes
    source: build
```

And in Dockerfile I am using the secret as following:

```
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=test_app_secret_id
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does adding [`environment: {"DOCKER_BUILDKIT": "1"}`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#to-enable-buildkit-builds) do what you expect?

Comment: I added DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 in /etc/environment this didn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

Building with buildkit is not (yet as of 21st November 2023...) supported by the Ansible `community.docker.docker_image` module. Quoting the [notes in documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_image_module.html#notes)

> Building images is done using Docker daemon’s API. It is not possible to use BuildKit / buildx this way.

So for time being, the solution is to go through shell setting the correct environment. Something like:

```yaml
- name: Build an image with BuildKit and push it to a private repo
  vars:
    image: local:5000/test
    tag: v1.1.2
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: |-
      docker build --secret "id=test_app_secret_id,src={{ tempfile_1.path }}" -t {{ image }}:{{ tag }} .
      docker push {{ image }}:{{ tag }}
    chdir: "{{ role_path }}/files/test"
  environment: 
    DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
```