# Build Docker Image with ansible requires Buildkit, but fails despite enabling buildkit in daemon and/or adding environment variable in ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, environment-variables, docker-image

I try to build a collabora Docker Image with ansible. Here is the code:

```yaml
    - name: Build collabora Docker image
      docker_image:
        source: build
        name: '{{ collabora_docker.image_name }}'
        tag: '{{ collabora_docker.version }}'
        build:
          path: '/tmp/collabora.git/docker/from-packages'
          nocache: yes
          dockerfile: Ubuntu
          args:
            type: cool
            secret_key: '{{ collabora_docker.key }}'    
      environment: 
        DOCKER_BUILDKIT: 1
```

It fails with the following error msg:

```
Error building repositoryxy/collabora - code: None, message: the --mount option requires BuildKit. Refer to https://docs.docker.com/go/buildkit/ to learn how to build images with BuildKit enabled
```

As you can see with the code above I already try to pass the environment variable via ansible but to no avail. See also [Use BuildKit for docker build within Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72021149/use-buildkit-for-docker-build-within-ansible)

I have also tried add the global setting to the docker daemon as described in https://docs.docker.com/build/buildkit/

Since I have BuildKit globally enabled in docker daemon.json, I can now manually build the image on the host with the same ansible user in question without setting the environment variable. Following command builds the docker image in question:
`docker build --no-cache --secret id=secret_key,src=secret_key --build-arg type=cool -t repositoryxy/collabora:22.05.8-4 -f Ubuntu .`

But when executed within the ansible playbook I'm still getting the above mention error message regarding buildkit not enabled.

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_image_module.html#notes => `Building images is done using Docker daemon’s API. It is not possible to use BuildKit / buildx this way.` <= Use command/shell with the corresponding env vars and docker command.

Comment: Thanks that seems to be the answer @Zeitounator 
I used the shell command. Seems less "elegant" but works.
Do you want to mark your comment as answer?

Comment: As the [other question you linked](/questions/72021149/use-buildkit-for-docker-build-within-ansible/74787816#74787816) is older, I answered there and will mark this one as duplicate once the answer is accepted or upvoted. Do not hesitate to edit my answer there if your final task looks a bit different of if I forgot something. Cheers.